# Select checkbox according to clicked item

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I created simple search using Vue.js components. The problem is that I do not know how to select specific checkbox. Right now I am collecting all the selected objects into array and removing them if necessary.

This is what I've done:

```
<template>
   <div class="list" v-if="is_opened">
      <div v-if="is_title_presented" class="list-title">
         {{title}}
         <i class="material-icons list-close-icon" @click="is_opened = false">clear</i>
      </div>
      <div class="list-item-container">
         <div class="searchBarMain">
            <input type="text" name="header-search" value="" id="searchBarInput" placeholder="Otsi kasutajat..." v-model="searchText">
         </div>
         <div class='list-item' v-for="(item, index) in filteredCustomers" :key="item.name" @click="$_test(item)">
            <div class="list-cell">
               <div class="list-item-icon">
                  <avatar :avatar_presented="item.avatar" :avatar="item.avatar" :name="item.name"></avatar>
               </div>
               <div class="list-item-text">
                  {{ item.name }}
               </div>
               <div class="list-item-selection" style="float: right;">
                  <input id="item.id" name="list-checkbox" type="checkbox"  v-model="item.id" :checked="true">
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</template>
```

And this is the logic:

```
data () {
    return {
      searchText: '',
      is_selected: false,
      items: [{avatar: '', name: 'John'}],
      filtered_items: [],
      selected_items: []
    }
  },

  methods: {
    $_test: function (item) {
      if (this.selected_items.includes(item)) {
        #Here I have to uncheck the selected item's checkbox and remove it from array
        console.log('Exists')
        this.selected_items.splice(this.selected_items.indexOf(item), 1)
      } else {
        #Here I have to check the selected item's checkbox and add it to the array
        console.log('Not existing')
        this.selected_items.push(item)
      }
    }
  },

  computed: {
    filteredCustomers:function() {
      var self=this;
        return this.items.filter(
          function(item) {
            return item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(self.searchText.toLowerCase())>=0;
          });
    }
  }
```

Is the object collecting method good approach to achieve the wanted effect?

Comment: you are using v-model="item.id" in your checkbox but you do not have key id in you items list, i think if you add id in you items array, everything works fine

Comment: can you recreate your problem on codesandbox? https://codesandbox.io/s/vue

Comment: @A.Lau I just did it. Here is the link: https://codesandbox.io/s/vvv5r7lr23

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you not just add a `selected` or `checked` key into your item object? You can just v-model it onto the input after that and check which items are checked.

https://codesandbox.io/s/9j3zk6o49o

changed html

```
   <div class="list-item-selection" style="float: right;">
      <input @change="$_test()" id="item.id" name="list-checkbox" type="checkbox" v-model="item.selected" :key="item.id">
   </div>
```

script changed

```
data() {
    return {
      searchText: "",
      is_selected: false,
      items: [
        {
          id: 0,
          avatar: "",
          name: "Tarvo",
          selected: true
        },
        { id: 1, avatar: "", name: "Lennart" },
        {
          id: 2,
          avatar: "",
          name: "Sven",
          selected: true
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          avatar: "",
          name: "Jaanus",
          selected: false
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          avatar: "",
          name: "Rain",
          selected: false
        }
      ],
      filtered_items: [],
      selected_items: []
    };
  },

  methods: {
    $_test: function(item) {
      let selected = this.items.filter(item => item.selected);
      console.log(selected);
    },

    $_removeTag: function(index) {
      this.selected_items.splice(index, 1);
    }
  },
```

Comment: But what if I want to select the checkbox if user clicks on the image or on the cell? Then I just have to change the item.selected = true?

Comment: @TarvoMäesepp yeah

Comment: Well you'll need to do a toggle instead. So something like `item.selected = !item.selected`

Answer (score 0):

In plain javascript you would (in your HTML) add an "id" on each checkbox. Then, in your javascript you would check if the checkbox was clicked or not by using following line:

var checkTheBox = document.getElementById('idToHtmlBox').checked;

...
Note! The result is stored in the variable checkTheBox, with value true or false.

Comment: vue functions quite differently to the point that you shouldn't be using vanilla javascript to access html elements.